# Enabling both multi-edit and single-edit styles in a TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In the mail app, you can swipe to delete a message. You can also hit edit, and select multiple messages, and delete them.

I want to be able to do the same in my table views.

I already had swipe to delete, by implementing the required delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // squish it.
    }
}
```

And then I found about this great new property apple introduced in iOS 5, `tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`. So, in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:)]) {
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    // set up a little toolbar to commit edits
}
```

And it worked, and that was fun... until I tried to swipe to delete again.

For some reason, the multi-edit functionality was preventing the standard swipe to delete style edit. I want both. Anyone know how to get both working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get swipe-to-delete working when tableView's allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing property is YES?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683516/how-do-i-get-swipe-to-delete-working-when-tableviews-allowsmultipleselectiondur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you can just set allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing to YES right before you enable editing mode on the tableview. Do this inside setEditing:animated:

Edit: Ah, it also looks like this has been answered already: [How do I get swipe-to-delete working when tableView's allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing property is YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683516/how-do-i-get-swipe-to-delete-working-when-tableviews-allowsmultipleselectiondur)